# problem when UIWebView to display gif image

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to display multiple images in a view. Images are downloaded from internet and are gif format.

This is what I did, but only the default broken icon is shown.

`_images` is a NSArray stored the path of image files

```
NSMutableString *html = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString *str in _images) {
    [html appendFormat:@"<img src='%@' />", str];
}

[_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

I tried this and image are displayed so I believe UIWebView are capable to display my images.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[_images lastObject]];
[_webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Or is any other good way to display multiple images? Otherwise I may have to create a UIImageView for each image and put them into a scroll view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIWebView should not have problems displaying .GIF images (as you proved in your test). The broken icon typically appears when the image is not found at the URL you provided. So might want to check your image URL (by opening the URLs in any browser).

Personally I would rather use a UIScrollView with UIImageViews in it. UIWebViews tend to be rather slow in loading and displaying their content. And if you want to react to user action on the images, UIWebView has another disadvantage: you need to implement some javascript event handling and there is a short but noticeable delay when the user taps on one of the images inside the UIWebView. If you go further and want to add swipe or other gesture recognition on your images you need to import a javascript library that does that. If you don't need user interaction on your images those disadvantages don't really count in your case. On the other hand using a UIWebView is quite handy because it automatically loads it's content asynchronously.

The UIScrollView with UIImageViews solution makes user interaction handling really easy. Just add UIGestureRecognizers to you images and off you go. On the other hand, if you have a lot of images or large images you cannot load them all at the same time or you'll run into memory warnings. So you might have to add some logic to only load the images that are currently displayed and release the ones that are not visible. You also have to implement async loading for your images to not block the scrolling while images are loading.

If your images all have the same size, you could use a UITableView to display the images and use it's build-in reuse of table cells to keep the memory footprint small. You still have to implement async loading though.

Anyway, I think there is no right or wrong in this case. If you do not need user interaction sing the UIWebView is easier and faster to implement but IMHO the UIScrollView / UITableView will still have the better user experience.